# What does this sticker say? (Characters identified: 萬事如意)

Tags: character-identification

I bought these stickers at a reuse store and I'm not sure what it says, and if the words seem fitting, I was going to put it on my binder I will use for my Mandarin classes.

[image]

Comment: Vertical text. Place them vertically.

Comment: Already answered, so I'll just provide character by character translation:
萬 (ten thousand)
事 (things/affairs)
如 (like/according to)
意 (though/desire)
So literally the phrase translates as "[May] ten thousand things [happen] as [one] wishes")

Comment: In future, this would be a suitable place to start: [How do I self-answer “What does this say?”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 3):

萬事如意 /wan4 shi4 ru2 yi4/ (May everything be as you wish)

This is one of those auspicious sayings people use around Chinese New Year. People often say this to one another, and/or write the four characters on red paper to use as wall decoration around Chinese New Year.

You can certainly use them to decorate your binder. Happy learning!

Answer (score 2):

萬事如意

Google translate: Good luck

My interpretation: May all things go your way